# Wordpress error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." on adding a theme option page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a theme setting page for my client. I want to add a theme options page to apply settings but I get Wordpress error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. I think I am using the right code but problem still exists.
Please help me out in figuring where I am wrong

```
/*
 * ADD THEME SETTINGS PAGE
 */
function vc_add_theme_settings_page(){
    add_theme_page('Theme Settings','Theme Settings', 'manage_options' , 'vc_theme_page', 'vc_theme_page_display' );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'vc_add_theme_settings_page');

/*
 * DISPLAY THEME SETTINGS PAGE
 */
function vc_theme_page_display(){
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Vc Theme Settings Page</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php settings_fields('vc_section'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('vc_theme_page'); ?>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  add_action('admin_init', 'vc_add_theme_settings_page'); //instead of this
  add_action('admin_menu', 'vc_add_theme_settings_page'); //try this
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Order your code at this way:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'vc_add_theme_settings_pages');
add_action('admin_head', 'theme_styles');
add_action('admin_init', 'vc_add_theme_settings_page');

function vc_add_theme_settings_page(){
    add_theme_page('Theme Settings','Theme Settings', 'edit_theme_options', 'manage_options', 'vc_theme_page_display' );
}
```

and try change

```
<?php do_settings_sections('vc_theme_page'); ?>
```

for

```
<?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
```